# How to preserve whitespace in a create form in django

Tags: python, django

I just wanted to know how to preserve whitespace while creating forms in Django. So if I had a create form, and i just created a post on my site, the whitespace needs to be preserved. for example.

```
text

text
```

the space in the middle is what i want preserved. But for now, it just groups them.

```
text text
```

it returns that. So please let me know how.

`forms.py`

```py
class AnnouncementsSectionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    is_pin = forms.BooleanField(label="pin announcement post", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AnnouncementsSection
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'is_pin')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }),
        }
```

so my model, views, and my template don't seem to be important for this. I am pretty sure, all the work is in `forms.py`. So please let me know how.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `crispyforms`. This will allow you to basically write your `html` into your `form` including `divs` etc. This way when you render the form, it will render as you have defined it. https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This is not a problem with the form. This is just how HTML works. If you try simply rendering HTML with extra spaces or newlines you would notice that they are ignored and are shown as only one space. (You should search for some WYSIWYG solution)

Comment: uh, could you show me some code @Abdul Aziz Barkat? Thanks!

Comment: @PacketLoss, i am using `crispy forms` while rendering my form. But it still doesn't work

Comment: @TheKingfisher if you don't want something very complicated use the [`pre` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) and put your content in that. Else as I said above search for some What you see is what you get (WYSIWYG) solutions. For example Tiny Mce is a popular solution used for WYSISYG.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat, it kind of works. But it's a mess though. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: hi, can you also answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750610/how-to-assign-model-fields-to-a-custom-variable-in-the-view-and-use-it-in-conte